# keydown not detected until window is clicked

Tags: javascript, focus, onload, keydown

In my web application I have an event listener for a key that opens a menu. This works just fine only AFTER I have clicked anywhere on the page. I have tried to add focus to the window onload...but this still does not let the keydown function run until after I have clicked somewhere on the page.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I can't imagine that it is not, but `.focus();` is not the goto as far as I have tried

Example of my primary function:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        // I have tried window.focus(); and window.document.focus(); 
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            var key = event.keyCode;
            if (key == 36) {
                toggleMenu();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: because the browser does not have focus?

Comment: @epascarello the browser should already be in focus. That's why this is such a head scratcher for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle here : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/7ebevbkw/)

Use `$(window).focus();` (with jquery)

**EDIT :**
Here's the solution in native javascript : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/tpg9wkLp/)

First the check_focus() function focuses on the window if the document doesnt have focus and then detects a keypress.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although this is working, I don't want to have to include a jQuery library just for this one function :/. A javascript answer would work best for my question.

Comment: @SpencerMay : Check the latest edit to my solution , I've added the solution in native javascript too.

Comment: it seems as though my original answer works. After reading your answer I tried it in a window and it still didn't work...then I tried in firefox and it worked. I must have some chrome setting off. I'm still a bit confuse. However, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, you might have the javascript turned off in chrome which is why it might not have worked, I've seen a few posts where people have had this issue wherein .focus() works for them on some browsers and in cases where it doesn't, either the chrome or FF javascript settings are turned off, since browsers give users the ability to allow/disallow scripts from focusing onto or loading a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help :

http://jsfiddle.net/yL67u5th/1/

```
$('#adaw').keydown(function (e) {
    var o = {
        45: 'INSERT',
        46: 'DELETE'
    };

    console.log(e.ctrlKey, e.shiftKey, e.which, o[e.which]);

    $('<div/>', {
        text: (e.ctrlKey ? 'CTRL and ' : '') + (e.shiftKey ? 'SHIFT and ' : '') + (o[e.which] ? o[e.which] : '') + ' was pressed!'
    }).appendTo('#adaw');

});
$('#adaw').focus();
```