# First click is being ignored after page load

Tags: javascript, onload

This webpage has a simple event listener, when I right click it blocks opening the context menu. simple enough.

But when I refresh the page or on initial load of the page, if I start with right mouse clicking the page, it shows the context menu, then blocks it ever time I right mouse click after that. I tried it in Chrome, FireFox and IE. Same results.

I experience the same thing with mouse down, keydown, or touch events, etc. It is like the first click is ignored. I am looking for JavaScript solution (not jquery). What am I missing?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    window.addEventListener("contextmenu", mouseright);
}
function mouseright() {
    document.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
        var e = e || window.event;
        alert("right");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
hello world
</body>
</html>
```

I even tried adding this before the event listener (as in this post [keydown not detected until window is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022716/keydown-not-detected-until-window-is-clicked)), had no luck with `document.onload` and did see that it could be a possible browser focus on page load setting. Any thoughts or other ideas I didn't try in JavaScript?

```
if (document.hasFocus() == true) {
  } else {
    window.focus();
  }
```

Comment: remove window.onload.
mouseright set upper than eventListener.

Comment: your first click fires before page loaded, I think, so you shouldn't wait while page is loaded

Comment: `mouseright()` gets called on the first click, but the `contextmenu` event already fired (it's how `mouseright()` was called).  Overwriting `oncontextmenu` won't change the *current* execution, but it will change the *next* execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unnecessarily assigning the event twice (as both `window.contextmenu` and `document.oncontextmenu`).  Removing the extra wrapper seems to work:

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.addEventListener("contextmenu", mouseright);
}
function mouseright(e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    alert("right");
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

(The `window.onload` may also be unneeded, depending on where you place the `addEventListener` in the document.)